# A function satisfying a vanishing property

Tags: calculus, functions

Is there a smooth function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, but $f'(x)/f(x)$ does not go to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$?

I'm especially interested in examples where $f'(x)/f(x)$ does not achieve arbitrarily high values as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Edit: Apologies, I had meant "does not go to $\infty$" in the original version. Now corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is the derivative of $\ln f(x)$. If $f(x)\to 0$ then $\ln f(x)\to-\infty$, which requires that the derivative of $\ln f(x)$ is unbounded. But this does not necessarily mean that it goes to $\infty$. Try
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x(2+\sin\tfrac 1x)&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases} $$
(The added $2$ is only an icing on the cake to prevent $f(x)=0$ for $x>0$).

Then $f'(x)$ oscillates between negative and positive values, hence $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ does not exist, not even in the extended reals.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an example where $f'(x)/f(x)$ is not even unbounded as $x\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @ougoah: Hagen Von Eitzen already argued that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ can't be bounded at $0$ as the derivative of $\ln(f(x))$ with $f(0)=0$.